# How to fill a B&W PNG icon with a color in Android?

Tags: android, tint, colorfilter

I want to fill PNG icons with colors.

Here is my current code:

```
            ingredientImageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("ico_" + ingredient.replace("-", "_"), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
            ingredientImageView.setColorFilter(iconTextColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

This code makes my icons like this:

[image]

iconTextColor here is black. But color filter fills the white parts of the icon. You can find the icon below:

[image]

Black lines should become the color that I want. But inside of the leaves(in that icon) should remain white.

So, transparent -> transparent, white->white, black->dynamicColor

How can I do that?

Comment: you wants to change full icon color ? or wants to fill color in specific part of the icon ?

Comment: try `imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR));` use mode which is appropriate for you.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Black lines should become the color that I want. But inside of the leaves(in that icon) should remain white. So, transparent -> transparent, white->white, black->dynamicColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define a custom ColorMatrix with random r g b values:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(256);
    int g = rand.nextInt(256);
    int b = rand.nextInt(256);

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.set(new float[] {
                        1, 0, 0, 0, r,
                        0, 1, 0, 0, g,
                        0, 0, 1, 0, b,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }); // last line is antialias
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, toX, toY, paint);
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I just set RGB values of my color, and set filter. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not change colours of .png icons but you can change colour of vector icon in xml form.
To change the colour of icon just import the icon with a different colour.

Comment: I do not agree with you. With filters, I am able to change the colors.

Comment: You can try to define a custom ColorMatrix with random r g b values as given below, try this

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure about your problem but whenever i need to change the color of .png images i just to be use **tint** method. you can see following code for help

**XML CODE**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ss"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
```

**java Code**

```
getBackground().setTint(tintColor);
```

Comment: I should use min sdk as 17

Comment: You can use following code below sdk 17                           
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_appcompat_imageview);

        final Drawable originalDrawable = imageView.getBackground();
        final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);